# How can we identify missing records of any entity when any input excel sheet is passed into Microsoft CRM Dynamics 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I want to import contact records in Microsoft CRM Dynamics 4.0 using csv file import option under Data Management.

The problem is I want to detect the records which are already there in CRM using csv file records when uploaded.

Please help, is there any way to achieve this. Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Could someone please help me out on this.

Comment: Very disappointed no one given any suggestion, not even they looked it to

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin on contact for the 'create' event as described in the SDK and then write code to detect duplicates.

[CRM 4.0 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38)

[Plugin Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151096.aspx)